# Fibonacci's Closed-form expression in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

How would the [Fibonacci's closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) code look like in **haskell**?

[image]

Comment: Choose a language already; you really expect one answer to give code for all of those?

Comment: Just write it yourself. The expression's given right there... do you really need other people to work for you?

Comment: The formula involves exponentiation, subtraction, and division. Can you please be more specific about which part of that you are having trouble with?

Comment: @ildjan: Not really... Wwhatever language you want, I added `haskell` because I think it could be easier, but a `c code` would be cool ...

Comment: Are you expecting the resulting code to give the exact n-th Fibonacci number, or an approximation? If it's the latter, then in my view there's not a lot to discuss. The former, on the other hand, is more interesting.

Comment: Seeing as you now narrowed this down to a specific language, I can live with that.

Comment: I've just verified, and a direct implementation using doubles gives correct (exact) answers to n=70. I'm voting to re-open hoping to see a discussion around whether Binet's formula can be used to get exact answers for n>70.

Comment: Amusingly, I recently wrote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327846/calculating-fibonacci/4328194#4328194 one (horrible) way of re-jiggering Binet's formula into giving exact answers.  Theoretically.  In practice you'll get bored past 20 ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trivially, Binet's formula, from [the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence#Using_Binet.27s_formula) page is given in Haskell as:

```
fib n = round $ phi ^ n / sq5
  where
    sq5 = sqrt 5 
    phi = (1 + sq5) / 2
```

Which includes sharing of the result of the square root. For example:

```
*Main> fib 1000
4346655768693891486263750038675
5014010958388901725051132915256
4761122929200525397202952340604
5745805780073202508613097599871
6977051839168242483814062805283
3118210513272735180508820756626
59534523370463746326528
```

For arbitrary integers, you'll need to be a bit more careful about the conversion to floating point values.
Note that Binet's value differs from the recursive formula by *quite a bit* at this point:

```
*Main> let fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) 
*Main> fibs !!   1000
4346655768693745643568852767504
0625802564660517371780402481729
0895365554179490518904038798400
7925516929592259308032263477520
9689623239873322471161642996440
9065331879382989696499285160037
04476137795166849228875
```

You may need more precision :-)

Answer (score 50):

Here's a straightforward translation of the formula to Haskell:

```
fib n = round $ (phi^n - (1 - phi)^n) / sqrt 5
  where phi = (1 + sqrt 5) / 2
```

This gives correct values only up to `n = 75`, because it uses `Double` precision floating-point arithmetic.

However, we can avoid floating-point arithmetic by working with numbers of the form `a + b * sqrt 5`! Let's make a data type for them:

```
data Ext = Ext !Integer !Integer
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Num Ext where
    fromInteger a = Ext a 0
    negate (Ext a b) = Ext (-a) (-b)
    (Ext a b) + (Ext c d) = Ext (a+c) (b+d)
    (Ext a b) * (Ext c d) = Ext (a*c + 5*b*d) (a*d + b*c) -- easy to work out on paper
    -- remaining instance methods are not needed
```

We get exponentiation for free since it is implemented in terms of the `Num` methods. Now, we have to rearrange the formula slightly to use this.

```
fib n = divide $ twoPhi^n - (2-twoPhi)^n
  where twoPhi = Ext 1 1
        divide (Ext 0 b) = b `div` 2^n -- effectively divides by 2^n * sqrt 5
```

This gives an exact answer.

---

Daniel Fischer points out that we can use the formula `phi^n = fib(n-1) + fib(n)*phi` and work with numbers of the form `a + b * phi` (i.e. ℤ[φ]). This avoids the clumsy division step, and uses only one exponentiation. This gives a much nicer implementation:

```
data ZPhi = ZPhi !Integer !Integer
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Num ZPhi where
  fromInteger n = ZPhi n 0
  negate (ZPhi a b) = ZPhi (-a) (-b)
  (ZPhi a b) + (ZPhi c d) = ZPhi (a+c) (b+d)
  (ZPhi a b) * (ZPhi c d) = ZPhi (a*c+b*d) (a*d+b*c+b*d)

fib n = let ZPhi _ x = phi^n in x
  where phi = ZPhi 0 1
```

Comment: Is this the same trick used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327846/calculating-fibonacci/4328194#4328194) ?

Comment: @Brian: It's quite similar. The first one is based on [the matrix formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form), but uses the same trick to get exponentiation for free. The second one does indeed use the same approach as I did, but it also uses [the binomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_expansion) to calculate only the required terms of (a + b√5)^n.

Comment: As a side note: this comes pre-defined in [Math.Algebra.Field.Extension](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellForMaths/0.1.9/doc/html/Math-Algebra-Field-Extension.html) (most of which I don't understand, but I used it successfully for this problem)

Comment: @Brian: Interestingly, it turns out that his second approach is much slower. It starts to choke at `n = 20`, while mine is virtually instant up to `n = 10^6`

Comment: @sleepyMonad: Nice! Although that's ℚ[√5], it might result in smaller intermediate numbers. I should try it and compare :)

Comment: @hammar: I have to say, this is **awesome**.  I have [some questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082640) that pertains to your answer so maybe you might be able to answer them.

Comment: What you need for this is `Z[(1+sqrt 5)/2]`, the ring of algebraic integers in `Q[sqrt 5]`. Nice is, with `phi = (1+sqrt 5)/2`, we have `phi^n = fib(n-1) + fib(n)*phi`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah, yes. That avoids the silly division which was annoying me. Also, that gives a nice way of calculating subsequent Fibonacci numbers since you get both `fib(n-1)` and `fib(n)` from it.

Comment: @hammar can you please elaborate more on the `ZPhi` multiplication case? I do not understand why is it any different than with the `Ext` case.

Comment: @haskelline: The core of the difference is that while `(√5)² = 5`, an integer, instead `φ² = 1 + φ`, which has both an integral and a `φ` component.  More lengthily: we have `(a₁ + b₁φ)(a₂ + b₂φ) = a₁a₂ + (a₁b₂ + a₂b₁)φ + b₁b₂φ²` by distributivity.  Since `φ² = 1 + φ`, the last term is `b₁b₂(1+φ)`, and so we can combine coefficients to get `(a₁a₂ + b₁b₂) + (a₁b₂ + a₂b₁ + b₁b₂)φ`.  In the `Ext` case, we instead have `(a₁ + b₁√5)(a₂ + b₂√5) = a₁a₂ + (a₁b₂ + a₂b₁)√5 + b₁b₂(√5)²`, and `(√5)²` is just `5`, so combining coefficients gets us `(a₁a₂ + 5b₁b₂) + (a₁b₂ + a₂b₁)√5`.  Does this help?