# Prolog - Finding the Nth Fibonacci number using accumulators

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I have this code to generate a list of the Fibonacci sequence in reverse order.

```
fib2(0, [0]).
fib2(1, [1,0]).
fib2(N, [R,X,Y|Zs]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    fib2(N1, [X,Y|Zs]),
    R is X + Y.
```

I only need the first element though. The problem is that this code also gives out a `false.` after the list, so all my attempts at getting the first element have failed. Is there any way I can get that first element in the list, or any other way of calculating the Nth Fibonacci number with accumulators.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does nobody mention these solutions: https://9gag.com/gag/apqNxqD ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this [logarithmic steps](https://kukuruku.co/post/the-nth-fibonacci-number-in-olog-n/) O(log n) solution, and even tail recursive.
Just for fun, it can also compute the n-th Lucas number:

```html
<pre id="in">
fib(N, X) :-
   powmat(N, [[0,1],[1,1]], [[1,0],[0,1]], 
             [[_,X],[_,_]]).
luc(N, Z) :-
   powmat(N, [[0,1],[1,1]], [[1,0],[0,1]], 
             [[X,Y],[_,_]]), Z is 2*X+Y.

powmat(0, _, R, R) :- !.
powmat(N, A, R, S) :- N rem 2 =\= 0, !,
   mulmat(A, R, H), M is N//2, mulmat(A, A, B), powmat(M, B, H, S).
powmat(N, A, R, S) :- 
   M is N//2, mulmat(A, A, B), powmat(M, B, R, S).

mulmat([[A11,A12],[A21,A22]], 
       [[B11,B12],[B21,B22]],
       [[C11,C12],[C21,C22]]) :-
   C11 is A11*B11+A12*B21,
   C12 is A11*B12+A12*B22,
   C21 is A21*B11+A22*B21,
   C22 is A21*B12+A22*B22.

?- fib(100,X).
?- luc(100,X).
</pre>
<script src="http://www.dogelog.ch/lib/exchange.js"></script>
```

You can compare with:

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fibonacci[100]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fibonacci%5B100%5D)
[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LucasN[100]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LucasN%5B100%5D)

**Edit 28.06.2021:**
Here is a very quick explanation why the matrix algorithm works.
We only need to show that one step of Fibonacci is linear. Namely
that this recurrence relation leads to linear matrix:

```
     F_{n+2} = F_{n}+F_{n+1}
```

To see the matrix, we have to assume that the matrix M, transforms a vector `b=[Fn,Fn+1]` into a vector `b'=[F_{n+1}, F_{n+2}]`:

```
      b' = M*b
```

What could this matrix be? Just solve it:

```
    |F_{n+1}|   |0*F_{n}+1*F_{n+1}|    |0  1|   |F_{n}  |
    |       | = |                 | =  |    | * |       |
    |F_{n+2}|   |1*F_{n}+1*F_{n+1}|    |1  1|   |F_{n+1}|
```

Answer (score 2):

It *gives out a "false"* because Prolog is unsure whether there are more solutions after the first one it provides:

```
?- fib2(4,L).
L = [3,2,1,1,0] ;  % maybe more solutions? 
false.             % no
```

This is not a problem: You can tell Prolog that there are indeed no more solutions after the first one (or that you are not interested in seeing them):

```
?- once(fib2(4,L)).
```

or

```
?- fib2(4,L),!.
```

or you can cut in each of the first clauses, telling Prolog that if the head matches, there is no point trying another clause. This gets rid of the stray "possible solution":

```
fib2(0, [0])   :- !.
fib2(1, [1,0]) :- !.
fib2(N, [R,X,Y|Zs]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    fib2(N1, [X,Y|Zs]),
    R is X + Y.
```

What may be a problem is that the given algorithm stores all the *fib(i)* and performs an addition after the recursive call, which means that Prolog cannot optimize the recursive call into a loop.

For the "accumulator-based" (bottom-up) way of computing *fib(N)*:

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------
% Proceed bottom-up, without using any cache, or rather a cache
% consisting of two additional arguments.
%
% ?- fib_bottomup_direct(10,F).
% F = 55.
% ------------------------------------------------------------

fib_bottomup_direct(N,F) :-
   N>0,
   !,
   const(fib0,FA),
   const(fib1,FB),
   up(1,N,FA,FB,F).
fib_bottomup_direct(0,F0) :-
   const(fib0,F0).

% Carve the constants fib(0) and fib(1) out of the code.

const(fib0,0).
const(fib1,1).

% Tail recursive call moving "bottom up" towards N.
%
% X:  the "current point of progress"
% N:  the N we want to reach
% FA: the value of fib(X-1)
% FB: the value of fib(X)
% F:  The variable that will receive the final result, fib(N)

up(X,N,FA,FB,F) :-
   X<N, % not there yet, compute fib(X+1)
   !,
   FC is FA + FB,
   Xn is X  + 1,
   up(Xn,N,FB,FC,F).
up(N,N,_,F,F).
```

Then:

```
?- fib_bottomup_direct(11,X).
X = 89.
```

Several more algorithms [here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/other_notes/about_fibonacci_numbers/fibonacci_various.pl); a README [here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/other_notes/about_fibonacci_numbers).

Comment: Note that `fib2(N, Xs)` produces an *incomplete* answer whereas the original produces two answers and an instantiation error thereafter.

Comment: I always find counting _down_ very confusing, when the computing is being done bottom-*up*. going from 0 up to N, might as well compare the counter with N and be done with it :) (just a personal peeve). it's conceptually better as well: the target value will be passed unchanged, simulating the (absent in Prolog) nested scope as it does; a smart compiler _might_ even  recognize that and use it to optimize the code, somehow.  well, in theory.

Comment: @WillNess Agree, that would be better.

Comment: @WillNess Changed the code to perform comparison instead of countdown.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses a tick less baggage, that is carried around.
The formulas are found at the end of the [wiki fibmat section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form):

```html
<pre id="in">
fib(N, X) :-
   powvec(N, (1,0), (0,1), (X,_)).
luc(N, Z) :-
   powvec(N, (1,0), (0,1), (X,Y)), Z is X+2*Y.

powvec(0, _, R, R) :- !.
powvec(N, A, R, S) :- N rem 2 =\= 0, !,
   mulvec(A, R, H), M is N//2, mulvec(A, A, B), powvec(M, B, H, S).
powvec(N, A, R, S) :- 
   M is N//2, mulvec(A, A, B), powvec(M, B, R, S).

mulvec((A1,A2), (B1,B2), (C1,C2)) :-
   C1 is A1*(B1+B2)+A2*B1,
   C2 is A1*B1+A2*B2.

?- fib(100,X).
?- luc(100,X).
</pre>
<script src="http://www.dogelog.ch/lib/exchange.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is "wiki fibmat section"? could you add the link to the answer please?

Comment: At the end of this section are two formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form

Answer (score 1):

`fib2(120,X), X=[H|_], !.` answers your question, binding `H` to the head of that reversed list, so, the 120th Fibonacci number.

Just insert the head-taking goal `X=[H|_]` *into* the query. Of course if you're really not interested in the list, you can fuse the two goals into one

```
fib2(120,[H|_]), !.
```

Your code does ~ 2N steps, which is still O(N) like an accumulator version would, so, not a big deal, it's fine as it is. The real difference is the O(N) space your version takes, v. the O(1) of the accumulator's.

But if you look closely at your code,

```
fib2(0, [0]).
fib2(1, [1,0]).
fib2(N, [R,X,Y|Zs]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    fib2(N1, [X,Y|Zs]),
    R is X + Y.
```

you realize that it creates the `N`-long list of uninstantiated variables on the way down to the deepest level of recursion, then calculates them while populating the list with the calculated values on the way back up -- but only ever referring to the last *two* Fibonacci numbers, i.e. the *first two* values in that list. So you might as well make it explicit, and end up with .... an accumulator-based version, yourself!

```
fib3(0, 0, 0).
fib3(1, 1, 0).
fib3(N, R, X) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    fib3(N1, X, Y),
    R is X + Y.
```

except that it's still not tail-recursive. The way to achieve that is usually with additional argument(s) and you can see such a code in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67976885/849891) here, by [David Tonhofer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884463/david-tonhofer). But hopefully you now see the clear path between it and this last one right here.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, an even **faster version of Fibonacci** (even without using tail recursion) is presented below:

```
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% FAST FIBONACCI
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

ffib(N, F) :-
    ff(N, [_, F]).

ff(1, [0, 1]) :- !.
ff(N, R) :-
    M is N // 2,
    ff(M, [A, B]),
    F1 is A^2   + B^2,
    F2 is 2*A*B + B^2,
    (   N mod 2 =:= 0
    ->  R = [F1, F2]
    ;   F3 is F1 + F2,
        R = [F2, F3]   ).

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% MOSTOWSKI COLLAPSE VERSION
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

fib(N, X) :-
   powvec(N, (1,0), (0,1), (X,_)).

powvec(0, _, R, R) :- !.

powvec(N, A, R, S) :-
   N rem 2 =\= 0, !,
   mulvec(A, R, H),
   M is N // 2,
   mulvec(A, A, B),
   powvec(M, B, H, S).

powvec(N, A, R, S) :-
   M is N // 2,
   mulvec(A, A, B),
   powvec(M, B, R, S).

mulvec((A1,A2), (B1,B2), (C1,C2)) :-
   C1 is A1*(B1 + B2) + A2*B1,
   C2 is A1*B1 + A2*B2.

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% COMPARISON
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

comparison :-
   format('n     fib   ffib  speed~n'),
   forall( between(21, 29, E),
      (  N is 2^E,
         cputime(fib( N, F1), T1),
         cputime(ffib(N, F2), T2),
         F1 = F2,        % confirm that both versions compute same answer!
         catch(R is T1/T2, _, R = 1),
         format('2^~w~|~t~2f~6+~|~t~2f~6+~|~t~2f~6+~n', [E, T1, T2, R]))).

cputime(Goal, Time) :-
   T0 is cputime,
   call(Goal),
   Time is cputime - T0.
```

The **time complexity** of both versions (mine and @MostowskiCollapse's) is *O*(lg *n*), ignoring multiplication cost.

Some simple **empirical results** (time in seconds) obtained with SWI-Prolog, version 8.2.4:

```
?- comparison.
n     fib   ffib  speed
2^21  0.05  0.02  3.00
2^22  0.09  0.05  2.00
2^23  0.22  0.09  2.33
2^24  0.47  0.20  2.31
2^25  1.14  0.45  2.52
2^26  2.63  1.02  2.58
2^27  5.89  2.34  2.51
2^28 12.78  5.28  2.42
2^29 28.97 12.25  2.36
true.
```

Comment: Very good! I guess the speed is not from if then else (->)/2, but rather from specializing mulvec(A,A,B). Mostlikely GMP, which is used by SWI-Prolog, can compute A^2 faster than A*B where B=A. Not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, replacing ^ with * does not change the speed significantly. Thus, I think you are right when you say that the gain in speed may be due to the specialization of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Slagos' version is called ["fast doubling"](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms) but MC's version is matrix exponentiation, streamlined using vectors. I don't think these are the same.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer It's nice to know! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This one uses the [Golden Ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41771104/502187) formula:

```html
<pre id="in">
fib(N, S) :-
   powrad(N,(1,1),(1,0),(_,X)),
   powrad(N,(1,-1),(1,0),(_,Y)),
   S is (X-Y)//2^N.
luc(N, S) :-
   powrad(N,(1,1),(1,0),(X,_)),
   powrad(N,(1,-1),(1,0),(Y,_)),
   S is (X+Y)//2^N.

powrad(0, _, R, R) :- !.
powrad(N, A, R, S) :- N rem 2 =\= 0, !,
   mulrad(A, R, H), M is N//2, mulrad(A, A, B), powrad(M, B, H, S).
powrad(N, A, R, S) :-
   M is N//2, mulrad(A, A, B), powrad(M, B, R, S).

mulrad((A,B),(C,D),(E,F)) :-
   E is A*C+B*D*5,
   F is A*D+B*C.

?- fib(100,X).
?- luc(100,X).
</pre>
<script src="http://www.dogelog.ch/lib/exchange.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't recognize it straight away but the base of this should be [The Linear Algebra View of the Fibonacci Sequence](https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/the-linear-algebra-view-of-the-fibonacci-sequence-4e81f78935a3)

Comment: There is yet another solution, respectively an improvement over this solution. Only raising one Golden ratio and then rounding. This possibly needs isqrt/2 to realize it without any floats, dunno yet.

Comment: Strange that nobody presented a memoization solution, like this here in Dogelog, which has now dynamic database: https://gist.github.com/jburse/ce2cc49168b637fb0472b3d958999c40#gistcomment-3798277

Comment: Maybe it doesn't match the op's question "accumulator".

Answer (score 0):

The Donald Knuth based Fibonacci-by-matrix multiplication approach, as provided by
[Mostowski Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502187/mostowski-collapse), but more explicit.

Algorithms can be found in the a *module* file plus a *unit tests* file [on github](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/other_notes/about_fibonacci_numbers):

The principle is based on a matrix identity provided by Donald Knuth (in Donald E. Knuth. The Art of Computer Programming. Volume 1. Fundamental
Algorithms, p.80 of the second edition)

[image: Extract from "The Art of Computer Programming. Volume 1"]

For n >= 1 we have (for n=0, the identity matrix appears on the right-hand side, but it is unclear what *fib(-1)* is):

```
                                  n
  [ fib(n+1) fib(n)   ]   [ 1  1 ]
  [                   ] = [      ]
  [ fib(n)   fib(n-1) ]   [ 1  0 ]
```

But if we work with constants *fib(0)* and *fib(1)* without assuming their value to be 0 and 1 respectively (we might be working with a special Fibonacci sequence), then we must stipulate that for n >= 1:

```
                                                       n-1
  [ fib(n+1) fib(n)   ]   [ fib(2) fib(1) ]   [ 1  1 ]
  [                   ] = [               ] * [      ]
  [ fib(n)   fib(n-1) ]   [ fib(1) fib(0) ]   [ 1  0 ]
```

We will separately compute the the "power matrix" on the right and explicitly multiply with the "fibonacci starter matrix", thus:

```
const(fib0,0).
const(fib1,1).

fib_matrixmult(N,F) :-
   N>=1,
   !,
   Pow is N-1,
   const(fib0,Fib0),
   const(fib1,Fib1),
   Fib2 is Fib0+Fib1,
   matrixpow(
      Pow,
      [[1,1],[1,0]],
      PowMx),
   matrixmult(
      [[Fib2,Fib1],[Fib1,Fib0]],
      PowMx,
      [[_,F],[F,_]]).
fib_matrixmult(0,Fib0) :-
   const(fib0,Fib0).

matrixpow(Pow, Mx, Result) :-
   matrixpow_2(Pow, Mx, [[1,0],[0,1]], Result).

matrixpow_2(Pow, Mx, Accum, Result) :-
   Pow > 0,
   Pow mod 2 =:= 1,
   !,
   matrixmult(Mx, Accum, NewAccum),
   Powm is Pow-1,
   matrixpow_2(Powm, Mx, NewAccum, Result).
matrixpow_2(Pow, Mx, Accum, Result) :-
   Pow > 0,
   Pow mod 2 =:= 0,
   !,
   HalfPow is Pow div 2,
   matrixmult(Mx, Mx, MxSq),
   matrixpow_2(HalfPow, MxSq, Accum, Result).
matrixpow_2(0, _, Accum, Accum).

matrixmult([[A11,A12],[A21,A22]],
           [[B11,B12],[B21,B22]],
           [[C11,C12],[C21,C22]]) :-
   C11 is A11*B11+A12*B21,
   C12 is A11*B12+A12*B22,
   C21 is A21*B11+A22*B21,
   C22 is A21*B12+A22*B22.
```

If your starter matrix is sure to be `[[1,1],[1,0]]` you can collapse the two operations `matrixpow/3` followed by `matrixmult/3` in the main predicate into a single call to `matrixpow/3`.

The above algorithm computes "too much" because two of the values in the matrix of Fibonacci numbers can be deduced from the other two. We can get rid of that redundancy. [Mostowski Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502187/mostowski-collapse) presented a compact algorithm to do just that. Hereunder expanded for comprehensibility:

The idea is to get rid of redundant operations in `matrixmult/3`, by using the fact that all our matrices are symmetric and actually hold
Fibonacci numbers

```
[ fib(n+1)  fib(n)   ]
[                    ]
[ fib(n)    fib(n-1) ]
```

So, if we multiply matrices A and B to yield C, we always have something of this form (even in the starter case where B is the
identity matrix):

```
[ A1+A2  A1 ]   [ B1+B2  B1 ]   [ C1+C2  C1 ]
[           ] * [           ] = [           ]
[ A1     A2 ]   [ B1     B2 ]   [ C1     C2 ]
```

We can just retain the second columns of each matrix w/o loss of
information. The operation between these vectors is not some
standard operation like multiplication, let's mark it with ⨝:

```
[ A1 ]    [ B1 ]   [ C1 ]
[    ] ⨝ [    ] = [    ]
[ A2 ]    [ B2 ]   [ C2 ]
```

where:

```
C1 = B1*(A1+A2) + B2*A1 or A1*(B1+B2) + A2*B1
C2 = A1*B1 + A2*B2
```

```
fib_matrixmult_streamlined(N,F) :-
   N>=1,
   !,
   Pow is N-1,
   const(fib0,Fib0),
   const(fib1,Fib1),
   matrixpow_streamlined(
      Pow,
      v(1,0),
      PowVec),
   matrixmult_streamlined(
      v(Fib1,Fib0),
      PowVec,
      v(F,_)).
fib_matrixmult_streamlined(0,Fib0) :-
   const(fib0,Fib0).

matrixpow_streamlined(Pow, Vec, Result) :-
   matrixpow_streamlined_2(Pow, Vec, v(0,1), Result).

matrixpow_streamlined_2(Pow, Vec, Accum, Result) :-
   Pow > 0,
   Pow mod 2 =:= 1,
   !,
   matrixmult_streamlined(Vec, Accum, NewAccum),
   Powm is Pow-1,
   matrixpow_streamlined_2(Powm, Vec, NewAccum, Result).
matrixpow_streamlined_2(Pow, Vec, Accum, Result) :-
   Pow > 0,
   Pow mod 2 =:= 0,
   !,
   HalfPow is Pow div 2,
   matrixmult_streamlined(Vec, Vec, VecVec),
   matrixpow_streamlined_2(HalfPow, VecVec, Accum, Result).
matrixpow_streamlined_2(0, _, Accum, Accum).

matrixmult_streamlined(v(A1,A2),v(B1,B2),v(C1,C2)) :-
   C1 is A1*(B1+B2) + A2*B1,
   C2 is A1*B1 + A2*B2.
```