# Check if the number a perfectSquare (number has more than 15 digits)

Tags: c#, c++, c, square-root

I wish to calculate the square root of a number which had more than 15 digits if possible for 100 digits it would be great

number like 100000000000000

Currently i am using C with integer as data type

```
int IsPerfectSquare(int number)
{

   if (number< 0)

   return 0;

   int root = (round(sqrt(number)));

    if(number == (root * root))

    {        
       return 1;    
    }    
    else
    {        
      return 0;    
    }
}
```

But does double or long double can hold 15 digits or more

Language is no bar.
I can code in C# as well

Thanks :)

Comment: Getting the square root is the hard bit. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432412/calculate-square-root-of-a-biginteger-system-numerics-biginteger) for a possible solution.

Comment: I think you shouldn't ask questions like this [during the competition](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2270488/dashboard#s=p2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can use `decimal` to get up to 29 digits and `BigInteger` to get arbitrarily many digits.

However, you'll need a different technique to tell if a 100 digit BigInteger is a perfect square, as there isn't an off-the-shelf "root" function that I'm aware of.

Comment: You could always use a variation of the babylonian method to converge on the square root of the number: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method

Comment: @Patashu: There are lots of ways to compute the square root of an integer. See the linked duplicate answers for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, You can check how many bigs long double can hold by using the following function:

```
 std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 << std::endl;
```

If you really want to deal with numbers with `100` digits, you need to code your own BigInteger class.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an integer in C is platform-dependant, so there is no guarantee of how many digits it can hold. You can look into the [GNU Multiple Precision math library](http://gmplib.org/) for dealing with big numbers in C.