# How to use Newton-Raphson method to find the square root of a BigInteger in C#

Tags: c#, biginteger, square-root, newtons-method

So I'm attempting to use the Newton-Raphson method to find the square root of a BigInteger.

Here is my code:

```
            private void sqrRt(BigInteger candidate)
            {
                BigInteger epsilon = new BigInteger(0.0001);
                BigInteger guess = candidate / 2;

                while (BigInteger.Abs(guess * guess - candidate) >= epsilon)
                {
                    // guess = guess - (((guess**2) - y)/(2*guess))
                    guess = BigInteger.Subtract(guess, BigInteger.Divide(BigInteger.Subtract(BigInteger.Multiply(guess, guess), candidate), BigInteger.Multiply(2, guess)));
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(guess));
                }
            }
```

The problem seems to be that the BigInteger is not precise enough to fall within the degree of accuracy of the epsilon in the while loop - i.e. it needs a decimal place.  My question is what/how/where do I convert to a double to make the while loop eventually return false?

Comment: ummm a `BigInteger` is for integers, not floating point math.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate square root of a BigInteger (System.Numerics.BigInteger)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432412/calculate-square-root-of-a-biginteger-system-numerics-biginteger)

Comment: So how would I do floating point math on very large numbers?

Comment: use `double` data type and for more accuracy you can use `decimal`

Comment: see the last three answers here (http://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?rd2&topic=178333&start=40#p1332062), the last bitwise square root is really the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong data type. In order to have decimal points, you would need to use [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx), [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx), [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), or [`Complex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Check the links of all these types so you can see their digits of precision.