# Math.Sqrt() when using BigInteger?

Tags: c#, math, math.sqrt

I need to make a `Math.Sqrt` calculation but it must support really big numbers so I'm trying to use `BigInteger` but `Math.Sqrt` doesn't support them.

Are there any other options? How can I do this calculation  and result is double ?

Sample :

```
sqrt 5 = 2,2360679774997896964091736687313 
sqrt 4789798765456456456 = xxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx norm.
```

Comment: `double` d = Math.Sqrt(3);

Comment: That makes little sense.  You will first have to write a BigDouble class so you can represent the result.

Comment: How big is "really big"? `double`s go quite high already

Comment: You could use the fact that `Log(Sqrt(x)) = Log(x) / 2`. Use a BigDecimal, though.

Comment: @SJuan76 The Math.Log method takes (double) or (double,double). I think the Math libary just doesn't have support of BigIntegers. Either the OP will have to self-implement (Newtons method) or find a library that does (Does anyone know of one?).

Comment: Does your code need to work with integers outside the range of `double` (which is pretty huge)? If not, you could convert to `double` first, then use `Math.Sqrt`, then convert back if you need to (and perform some checks for boundaries)

Comment: @NathanCooper There is a `BigInteger.Log`... but anyway, for this method to work, it should deal with decimals, and it seems .Net lacks a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: please help me I cant

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate square root of a BigInteger (System.Numerics.BigInteger)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432412/calculate-square-root-of-a-biginteger-system-numerics-biginteger)

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa its not working

Comment: @...everyone I found the question confusing and commented on the basis that the OP wanted a BigInteger outputs for BigInteger inputs, which I'm not convinced it correct.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is probably to run [Newton's method for square roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number) starting with a double-precision initial guess.

To speed this up, notice that Newton's method doubles its precision with every iteration.  You can double your precision with every iteration as well by keeping track of an int32 "exponent" together with your `BigInteger` "mantissa", increasing the precision of the "mantissa" by a factor of two with each step until sufficient precision is reached.

Comment: BigInteger.pow(0.55,x) is possible ?