# Accuracy of double Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

When I enter 0.1 as a double value the compiler is adding a tiny value on the end of it that is causing other calculations to go wrong in the program that I am running. My code simply says:

```
double temp = 0.1;
```

And I get this in variable viewer:
http://img.skitch.com/20111122-nnrcgi4dtteg8aa3e8926r3fd4.jpg

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of many, many questions; I picked one, but if someone can find a better one, that's swell too.

Comment: A useful link (but not a useful SO answer): http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`double` is a floating *binary* point type. In binary, the value of "a half" is 0.1, and the value of "a quarter" is 0.01 etc. There is no way of *exactly* representing "a tenth" in a finite binary representation, any more than you can exactly represent "a third" in decimal. The compiler is giving you the closest value it can to the value you've *actually* asked for.

If you want to store decimal values precisely because you care about the decimals (e.g. for current) you should use a decimal-based type such as [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or an integer scaled appropriately (e.g. storing 15 for 15 cents instead of 0.15 dollars).

I have articles on [binary](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) floating point in .NET - `NSDecimalNumber` in Objective-C is slightly different to `decimal` in C# (see the documentation), but hopefully those articles will give you a bit more insight into what's actually happening.

EDIT: As noted in comments, typically decimal floating point types are significantly slower than binary floating point types, partly because they're often larger and partly because they don't have CPU support. If you have a hard performance requirement *and* you want to retain digits precisely, the "integer and implied scale" option is usually a good one, though a pain to code against as you need to take it into account every time you read the code :)

Comment: Yes, there is. It is the NSDecimalNumber class.

Comment: @LuizCarlosQuerinoFilho: Thanks, I'll adjust accordingly.

Comment: Nice to see J.Skeet on objective C posts, perfect answer as always, just want to emphasize the performance drawbacks of NSDecimalNumber compared to a C double, if large amounts of operations are required.

Comment: @jbat100: Will mention that. Typically where it matters, it's better to be slow than wrong :)

Comment: +1, but what is the meaning of "decimal floating point types are significantly slower than decimal floating point types" ?

Comment: @Maudicus: Whoops, typo - fixed, thanks.